# Funciones en un Preloader

Tags: html, jquery, css, funciones

Resulta que estuve diseñando un preloader en la página web que estoy desarrollando, todo bien. Funcionan las funciones que puse en su código, por cierto para ello estoy usando **Jquery**.

El código es el siguiente:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("#loading").delay(1500).fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Resulta que aun no he podido identificar como destruir el script.

Me explico: Quiero que una vez que se ejecute mi página por primera vez, funciona, pero luego en cada sesión o subpágina a la que ingreso dentro de mi sitio se ejecuta estas funciones. Lo que busco es que solo ejecute estas funciones 1 sola vez, cuando se inicie la página en su página principal, pero para sus subpáginas, no lo quiero, es muy molesto que el preloader esté cargando cada vez que se traslada.

Si pudieran ayudarme con esto les agradecería mucho.

No se mucho sobre programar, pero en algo me defiendo.
Saludos y Muchas gracias.

Comment: Simplemente no incluyas ese script en las otras paginas, solo en tu pagina principal, a no ser que estes usando plantillas con un framework, si es asi coméntanoslo para poder ayudarte

Comment: Ya lo solucione, resulta que había otra persona que realizó una conexión entre el index y otra pagina donde se almacenaban variables. Solucione, pegando el preloader y llamando allí la hoja de estilos y el script. Funcionó. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Ah bueno, esta bien